# How to clone button between tabs C# Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, button, clone, tabcontrol

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SBbk.png)

Hi! How can I clone a button on other tabs? I need the same button in many tabs, the same button with the same proprieties, same code, same events, same name, ect.

"Compress file" button is going to be the same in Tab1, Tab4, Tab6 and Tab8... is going to do the same thing in many tabs, therebefore I don't want to make a new button every time. I don't want to make 10000 buttons which do the same thing.

I need to clone many buttons, not just "compress file", that's why I can't just put "Compress file" outside the TabControl and make it invisible or visible.

I'm working on Visual Studio 2015 with C#.

Comment: You'll end up making your 10000 buttons, but hook all of their click events up to the same click handler.

Comment: You can create a custom control that sets the default properties and default click handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a generic function, feel free to add more parameters to make it more flexible:

```
void CreateButton(TabControl tc, string text, EventHandler click)
{
    Button button = new Button();
    button.Width = 100;
    button.Height = 100;
    button.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
    button.Text = text;

    button.Click += click;

    tc.Controls.Add(button);
}
```

Usage:

```
CreateButton(Tab1, "Compress file", Button_Click);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need just to add your button on front of your `TabControl` not on one of the tab pages, so it will be shown on all of your tab pages but if you have to change its location, you should change the location of the button programmatically each time you switch to other tab page. Also, if you don't need it to be shown on some of the tab pages then you should make it invisible on that tab page.
Anyway, I really don't like to do it this way, but I would rather to add all the buttons I need on each tab and connect all of them on the same events' handlers.

**NOTE**: if you could not add the button on front of your tab control, you can use view > Other Windows > Document Outline to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Create your button in developer code.  Then later on use the reference to add it to the controls for each tab as you switch tabs. e.g.

```
public MyForm()
{
    Initialize();
    Button MyOneTrickButton = new Button();
    //Create button with all attributes and actions
    ...
}

void MyTabControl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyTabControl.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(MyOneTrickButton);
}
```

A second option is to create a custom TabControl containing your button and use that instead of the normal TabControl when adding to the tabs to the form.

Answer (score 0):

Add new User Control to your project and a button to with Click event.
Code behind:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Add some public properties to Caculate
    public string SomeProperties { get; set; }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Some tasks that you often do ...........

    }
}
```

You could use it in any where you want.